# Search and print matching string present in both files

Tags: shell

I have `./all_files/reference_file.txt` which has data as shown below.

reference_file.txt contains filenames as shown

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
file5.txt
```

data in all files are as shown below:

```
step_1
step_2
step_3
step_4
```

Now, I have to take particular step say step2 from each file

Note1: file name must present in reference_file.txt

Note2: step2 is not line no:2 always.

Note3: search should perform recursively.

I have used below code

```
#!/bin/sh

while read f; do
    if [ -f "$f" ]; then
       find . -type f -name "*.txt" | xargs  grep -l -F 'step_2' "$f"
    fi
done <reference_file.txt
```

please help me on this

Comment: What is the purpose of your `find` command

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: @fazlin the purpose of find is to search the required recursively

Comment: @LeeHoYo the desired output should be `file1.txt: step2, file2.txt: step2, file3.txt: step2`

Answer (score 0):

Two changes to your code:

- Remove the `if` because `find` is supposed to find the file and in
  that case `if` might return false if the file is not in current
  directory.
- `find` command should be passed `$f` as argument.

Below is the updated example:

```
while read f; do
   find . -type f -name "${f}" | xargs  grep -l -F 'step_2'
done <reference_file.txt
```

Comment: thank you, but when i used above code as it is, i didn't have any output. please let me know if i need to change anything

Comment: it has all necessary permission.. what i mean to say the script output is empty, even if some output is expected.

Comment: I am not talking about permission.. run the script as `bash -x script.sh` to see the debug info

Comment: here is the ouput `+ find . -type f -name file1.txt`
`+ xargs grep -l -F 'step_2'` `+ find . -type f -name ''`
`+ xargs grep -l -F 'step_2'`
`+ read f` it is displaying all the lines in reference.txt file(incudes blank and unmatched lines)

Comment: someone please help me on this.. instead of above code i tried another one.. `#!/bin/sh`

`for i in reference_file.txt`

`do`
`find . -type f -name *.txt | xargs  grep -l -F 'step_2'`
`done < reference_file.txt`  but it is only searching one folder but not searching all sub folders recursively.